# Wp backend page content not showing, but actual page is fine

Tags: dashboard

I'm having a little problem where, well long story short, i get told to "fix" a WordPress gallery etc...be it add/remove images or whatever but when i log in and go to that page, be it in "visual" or "HTML" view, there's nothing in the content area.

like i don't see **anything** in there. its blank like if it was a new page.

i expect to see something liek  short code or you know, something like for example
`**[gallery link="file"]**` or something but again, nothing shows on the backend.

Now when i go to that same page on the actual live site, and or when i click on the "view page" to preview, the page and its content is show up just fine.

Any ideas as to whats going on? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The page could just be a shell. Check to see if a plug-in, template, or something else is inserting the content dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the page template setting - is it set to default?  If not, look at the code for the template itself.  I've seen new WP devs manually insert scripts and codes directly into the template rather than enqueue in `functions.php`.

What plugin is being used to manage the gallery?

Answer (score 1):

Somdow.

The problem is in charset of db.
Open wp-config.php file and just change charset to utf8 & comment the old one.

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, it solved my issue. my config file had the following line 
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4'); and I changed to 'utf8'

Comment: unfortunately, few are still not fixed :(